# Save a specific BoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript

I'm using getBoundingClientRect to change an elements position to absolute without changing it's position:

```
   style.position = 'absolute'
   style.top = container.getBoundingClientRect().top
   style.left = container.getBoundingClientRect().left
   style.width = container.offsetWidth
```

I do this to later transition the element to fullscreen, like this:

```
  style.top = 0
  style.left = 0
  style.width = '100%'
  style.height = '100%'
  style.transitionProperty = 'top, left, width, height'
  style.transitionDuration = '.2s'
```

Style is a javascript object that gets converted to css-properties.

Later on I want to close the full-screen-thing and revert the element back to it's original size. I would like to save the values from getBoundingClientRect as they are at the first transition. Can this be done?

Comment: If you already have these values in your `Style` object what is specific problem?

Comment: When I change the size of the element, the values change and I have over-written the valuew with 0 and 100%, so I need to save them somehow until later.

Comment: can store the object returned by `getBoundingClientRect()` as a different property of the element ...then access it later through that same property name

Comment: You mean convert it to a string basically?

Comment: not really , no need to convert it's type `container.originalRect = container.getBoundingClientRect()`. But can also store it in a variable , or localStorage or wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done. Like this:

```
var bcr = container.getBoundingClientRect();
style.width = '100%';
// later
style.width = bcr.width;
```

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
var bcr = null;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (bcr) { // Currently fullscreen
    el.style.position = '';
    el.style.top = bcr.top + 'px';
    el.style.left = bcr.left + 'px';
    el.style.width = bcr.width + 'px';
    el.style.height = bcr.height + 'px';
    bcr = null;
  } else {
    bcr = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
    el.style.top = el.style.left = 0;
    el.style.width = el.style.height = '100%';
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Toggle fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

That said, most probably you don't need it, because just assigning the styles to the empty string will do the trick.